# can't delete or update item in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

when i tried delete item in laravel i get this message

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`larblog`.`comments`, CONSTRAINT `comments_article_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`article_id`) REFERENCES `articles` (`id`)) (SQL: delete from `articles` where `id` = 2)

this my delete function

```
 public function DeleteArticle($id){
        $article = Article::find($id);
        $article->delete();
        return redirect("article");
    }
```

this create articles table code

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateArticle extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('articles');
    }
}
```

and this create comments table code

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateComments extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->text('comment');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->integer('article_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('article_id')->references('id')->on('articles');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('comments');
    }
}
```

Iam tried to use this solution but did not work

```
$table->foreign('article_id')->references('id')->on('articles')->onUpdate('cascade')- 
>onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: where did u put this code? $table->foreign('article_id')->references('id')->on('articles')->onUpdate('cascade')- 
>onDelete('cascade');

Comment: public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->text('comment');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->integer('article_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('article_id')->references('id')->on('articles')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

Comment: Your referenced foreign keys must be `bigInteger` or `unsignedBigInteger` as in `$table->unsignedBigInteger('article_id');` as explained in https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you know your comments depends on articles once a article is delete then comment's relation going to break so either you first delete all comment's of that artical or set foreign key null to all the comment for that article
so that why you need to update your mygration with

`$table->foreign('article_id')->references('id')->on('articles')->onDelete('cascade');`

or

`$table->integer('article_id')->unsigned()->nullable();`

`$table->foreign('article_id')->references('id')->on('articles')->onDelete('set null');`

Comment: iam already updated code in migration folder in create_comments.php  file
to 
$table->foreign('article_id')->references('id')->on('articles')->onDelete('cascade');
but didn't work, I told this in the end of post above
and now tried use
$table->foreign('article_id')->references('id')->on('articles')->onDelete('set null');
but didn't work also
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: after doing this you need do you run migration again 
like php artisan migrate:fresh note this flash you old data so if you need data the you need to change into your database manually

Comment: thank you raghav, it is worked successfully when i run this order ( artisan migrate:fresh ), good luck :)